# How to post with references in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have Comment model related with User model

```
# models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    more fields...
    ....
```

In the serializer I want to do a create (POST) of a user comment.
But the post method is not enabled, only the put or patch method

Example: User Jon wants to create a comment

```
# serializers.py

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__'

class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # id of comment
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="user-comments-detail",
        read_only=True
    )    
    id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    comment = CommentSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'comment']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        comment_data = validated_data.pop('comment')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Comment.objects.create(user=user, **comment_data)
        return user
```

I want to new comment, referencing the user

```
# views.py
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCommentSerializer
```

But I have an exception, that the user has no comment `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`

My url like this

http://localhost:8000/user-comments/10

10 is a user_id pk

{} object post

Example: `Comment.objects.create(user=pk, {})`

Currently, only put and patch is enabled, but what I want to do is post of user

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/user-comments/10",
    "id": "10",
    "comment": null
}
```

Comment does not exist

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean with "make a comment"? Are you trying to create a new `Comment` record in the database?

Comment: @HuLuViCa Exactly I want to create a new comment

Comment: @BriseBalloches Sorry I fixed typo

Comment: @BriseBalloches same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need just one serializer for that.

This will create a comment for the current logged in user.

```py
# serializers.py

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ['user']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # get the user who sent the request
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return Comment.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)


# views.py

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        # this is important since you want to pass the request object to your serializer
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is because `ModelSerializer` is linked to a specific model, in this case you linked `UserCommentSerializer` to model `User`. Variable `Meta.fields` specifies which fields of the model are being returned by the serializer and, so, you are getting an exception because such variable is set to `('id', 'comment')` and model `User` doesn't have a field `comment`.

You can achieve what you want, this way:

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id']
        extra_kwargs = {'comment': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        comment_data = validated_data.pop('comment')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Comment.objects.create(user=user, comment=comment_data)
```

Comment: Not working, I edited the question with more details

Comment: @Alejandro You're are trying to create a user with no data in it. What I don't understand is if the user is **already** created and thus you can use request.user, or if you want to create the user **and** the comment at the same time ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches The user is already created, I only need to create the comment, the way I am doing it, does not enable the post method.